# Node.js AWS-SDK: Object has no method 'upload'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to stream a webshot upload to S3. When I put together the AWS S3 object, I'm being told it has no 'upload' method:

```
var s3obj = new aws.S3({params: {Bucket: 'whatever', Key: 'idksomefile' }});
s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
              on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
              send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'upload'
```

Any idea why this is exploding?

Answer (score 1):

When you create `s3obj` from `aws.S3` you should only pass a `Bucket` parameter, and then set the `Key` in the `upload` method parameters.

**From the AWS documentation:** [found here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html)

```
var s3obj = new aws.S3({params: {Bucket: 'whatever'}});
s3obj.upload({Key: 'idksomefile', Body: body}).
              on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
              send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Your `body` variable may be a `Stream` object, in which case you will need to use `.toString()`:

```
var s3obj = new aws.S3({params: {Bucket: 'whatever'}});
s3obj.upload({Key: 'idksomefile', Body: body.toString()}).
              on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
              send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

Comment: No dice on this one, either. Just seems like the s3 object doesn't have the upload method at all.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure you're authenticated? What do you get if you `console.log(s3obj)` ??

Comment: What should I see if I AM authenticated? Lots of code to post. It should be all good. Updating to 2.1.13 as advised about got me past the missing method error - getting a different error now: stream has no method 'read'

Comment: Is your `body` variable a Stream? If so, you'll need to change to `body.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1:
Please check your aws-sdk version and make sure its 2.1.13 to later.

Try to specify the key inside the upload function. see [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Basic_Usage_Example)

```
var s3obj = new aws.S3({params: {Bucket: 'whatever'}});
s3obj.upload({Key: 'idksomefile', Body: body}).
              on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
              send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

Comment: No dice on that. Still get the same error. I'm really stumped here - this seems to be a problem unique to me :P

Comment: did you require the AWS Node.JS SDK as the variable aws?

Comment: Yep. Everything seems to be kosher.

Comment: Re: Edit 1 - Seems to be good now! Onto the next problem: object #<Stream> has no method 'read'!